# An abundance of one-line Rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus, english

Solve the following ten one-line Rebus puzzles:

1. AGE BUT
2. marri Ag e
3. wWoOlOfL
4. "24 Hours"
5. TRADI$~$ TION
6. HEAD ACHE
7. WHEATHER
8. SGEG
9. TOSYOBSYOBWN
10. ALL world

Comment: Awesome puzzle! Keep making more rebus puzzles like these. Love it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am going to combine all answers so that it is easy for everyone to see.
All credit goes to Hellion, Gamow and Vikram.

1. AGE BUT

   > **Age before beauty** (B-U-T)
2. marri Ag e

   > Ag=silver with marriage = **Silver wedding anniversary**
3. wWoOlOfL

   > Wolf in WOOL = **Wolf in sheep's clothing**
4. "24 Hours"

   > Multiple possibilities:
   >  **Call it a day**
   >  **Quote of the day**
5. TRADI  TION

   > **Break with tradition**
6. HEAD ACHE

   > **Splitting headache**
7. WHEATHER

   > **Bad spell of weather**
8. SGEG

   > Permutation of EGGS = **Scrambled eggs**
9. TOSYOBSYOBWN

   > BOYS BOYS backwards, inside TOWN = **The Boys are Back in Town**
10. ALL world

    > **It's a small world after all!**

Comment: Hello! As this is a compilation of existing answers, I've converted it to Community Wiki. CW posts are intended to be collaborated on by all users of the site, and don't earn their owners reputation. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 11):

1:

> Age before Beauty ("B, U, T")

7: (just a guess here)

> Bad spell of weather

10:

> It's a small world after all.

Comment: 1 and 10: great solutions! For 7, I think it should rather be "spell of bad weather".

Comment: @Gamow, I think you've got it.  Changed my answer to suit.  (with one slight alteration.)

Answer (score 10):

The answers for 2, 3, 8, and 9:

2:

> "Ag=silver with marriage" = **"Silver wedding anniversary"**

3:

> "wolf in WOOL" = **"Wolf in sheep's clothing"**

8:

> "SGEG = permutation of EGGS" = **"Scrambled eggs"**

9:

> "SYOBSYOB = BOYS BOYS backwards, inside TOWN" = **"The Boys are Back in Town"**

and the answer for 7 in collaboration with Hellion

7:

> "badly spelled version of WEATHER" = **"Spell of bad weather"**

and perhaps an answer for

5:

> "a break in TRADITION" = **"Break with tradition"**

Answer (score 6):

2>

> uneven marriage

4>

> All day packed

5>

> break the tradition

6>

> splitting headache

Comment: I think the 6th one is correct.

Comment: What is "all day packed"?  I've never heard this phrase and a Google does not come up with anything promising right off hand.

Comment: @feelinferrety I had this same thought

Answer (score 6):

Possibility for #4:

> Quote of the day

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for #4:

> Calling it a day