# My teacher gave me a puzzle one day

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, letters, real

I told my teacher that I liked riddles and puzzles. As a matter of fact, I introduced him to the Puzzling Stack Exchange! Then, he got a sheet of paper, asked for a pen, and when he found one (I didn't have a pen on me, as usual) he wrote something on it.

I was on my computer, writing my anagram puzzle, when he then handed me the sheet of paper. I looked at it and saw what was written on it. This is what it said:

---

$$$$
$$\color{red}{\LARGE \rm T\quad I\quad M\quad E}$$ $$\small\color{red}{\rm ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$$
$$$$

---

(It was written with a red pen.) I asked him what it meant, and he said it was a riddle. I then said that it wasn't a riddle — it was some kind of enigmatic puzzle. And then he asked if I could figure it out and went to lunch as it was the end of class.

What does it mean? I noticed that the alphabet is missing the letter $\rm C$, and the $\rm B$ looked like a $13$ in his handwriting. Was it some kind of message I had to figure out? Perhaps it said "Time's up" since the word *TIME* is above (up) the alphabet and a clock only has $12$ hours (not $13$)? I didn't know.

Has anyone seen this puzzle before? Would you like me to upload a picture of the original piece of paper? I am unsure what tags I should include, so they might not help. Also, I don't know the name of the puzzle if it is well-known, so I can't research it.

(True story.)

Comment: @Chowzen thanks for the edit. I didn't know which was the right tag to use :)

Comment: Don't forget that if you showed your teacher the Puzzling Exchange, there's a good chance they'll end up seeing this question too.

Comment: @LordFarquaad hahah, well, lucky I am an honest person. I have already told my teacher today :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think it's one of those rebus puzzles. :)

> Long time no see

Comment: This has to be it. No explanation needed. I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier — why didn't I think of this? Eh well, I will give others a shot at this if they haven't seen the puzzle, before accepting yours. (I also reached my daily voting limit, and have to wait $14$ hours before I can upvote.) :D

Comment: Just did some research on rebus puzzles. (SPOILER ALERT) So for example, the answer to `GESG` would be **scrambled eggs** because you can scramble the letters of EGGS to make GESG. Are those what rebus puzzles are? Like pictograms?

Comment: @user477343 This is a kind of rebuses that use only text, like in [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9000/32339)

Comment: @user477343 SE tags can have a "wiki", which generally has some helpful description of what the tag is for.  For example, the [rebus tag wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/rebus/info) has a short explanation of what a rebus is.

Comment: LOL okay I had to LOL at this one.  I'd never guess

Comment: Well, congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @DavidStarkey ah yes, I should have thought of that. Thanks for telling me :)